# How to Grouping Endpoint by Middleware in Go Fiber?

Tags: go, go-fiber

I'm encountering an issue with route setup in Go using Fiber.

```
app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("Hello, World!")
    })
    basicAuth1 := basicauth.New(basicauth.Config{
        Users: map[string]string{
            "go": "123",
        },
        Unauthorized: func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
            return fiber.NewError(fiber.StatusForbidden, "Error BasicAuth V1")
        },
    })
    basicAuth2 := basicauth.New(basicauth.Config{
        Users: map[string]string{
            "go": "321",
        },
        Unauthorized: func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
            return fiber.NewError(fiber.StatusForbidden, "Error BasicAuth V2")
        },
    })
    base := app.Group("/api")
    v1 := base.Group("/", basicAuth1)
    v1.Get("/v1", func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return ctx.SendString("a from v1")
    })

    v2 := base.Group("/", basicAuth2)
    v2.Get("/v2", func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return ctx.SendString("a from v2")
    })

    app.Listen(":3000")
```

When I attempt to access the `api/v2` endpoint, I receive an error from the basicAuth1 middleware.
This middleware should only be applied to a different group and not affect `api/v2`.
I didn't experience this issue with similar middleware usage and group configuration in Echo. and I just want grouping handler by middleware.

[`api/v1` with correct auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAGZg.png)

[`api/v2` with correct auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sD2g.png)

Grouping endpoint by its Middleware

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're experiencing this issue because you're attaching both `basicAuth1` and `basicAuth2` to the same base group (`base`). When you define `v1` and `v2` groups, you're attaching the respective basic auth middleware to them, but you're not removing or overriding the middleware from the parent group (`base`).

To resolve this issue you can structure code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2/middleware/basicauth"
)

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    base := app.Group("/api")

    v1 := base.Group("/v1", basicauth.New(basicauth.Config{
        Users: map[string]string{
            "go": "123",
        },
        Unauthorized: func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
            return fiber.NewError(fiber.StatusForbidden, "Error BasicAuth V1")
        },
    }))
    v1.Get("/", func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return ctx.SendString("a from v1")
    })

    v2 := base.Group("/v2", basicauth.New(basicauth.Config{
        Users: map[string]string{
            "go": "321",
        },
        Unauthorized: func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
            return fiber.NewError(fiber.StatusForbidden, "Error BasicAuth V2")
        },
    }))
    v2.Get("/", func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return ctx.SendString("a from v2")
    })

    app.Listen(":3000")
}
```

I have attached the `basicauth` middleware directly to each sub-group **(`v1` and `v2`)** rather than attaching it to the base group (`base`). This way, each group has its own middleware configuration, and endpoints within those groups will only be affected by the middleware attached to their specific group.

### Testing /api/v1 endpoint:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1 -u go:123
```

### Testing /api/v2 endpoint:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/v2 -u go:321
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice.

But is it possible to group routes based on middleware in Fiber? Like my example at the beginning, maybe in my example I will add a new endpoint, namely `/api/go`. This API is the result of a group from v2. Something like this:

```
  v2.Get("/go", func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return ctx.SendString("go from v2")
    })
```

Is it possible if i hit `/api/go` ?

Comment: is this works for you ? ` v := base.Group("/", basicauth.New(basicauth.Config{
        Users: map[string]string{
            "go": "123",
        },
        Unauthorized: func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
            return fiber.NewError(fiber.StatusForbidden, "Error BasicAuth from route: go ")
        },
    }))
    v.Get("/go", func(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return ctx.SendString("a from route :go")
    })`